# Libraries are not hooked up correctly in android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I'm new to android development. And at the moment I'm using `android studio` for development. Now I need to make changes in a project. So I imported the project. But when I build a get errors on the library `actionbar sherlock`.

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. 
adding it to manifest helped me..

```
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
>
```

Comment: still got the same errors. Think that it can't reach my libraries